# javascript: use getElementsByName for 'this'?

Tags: javascript

I need to get some children elements and loop over them using inline javascript for a onmouseover event.  When I try to use this.getElementsByName I'm getting an error that the object does not support this property. I was under the impression that getElementsByName work for element objects which I thought 'this' would be considered.  Anyone have any other ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Obviously you should provide the problematic code.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Perhaps you mean getElementsByTagName? A code example would be great.

Comment: yes, code please. in your context what is `this` ?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` only exists on the `document` level.

Also what kind of elements are you trying to access? Because the `name` attribute only exists for links (`a` elements) and form elements (`input`, `select`, etc.).

If you have several elements which you want to give the same "name", you may consider giving them a class instead, however you'd most likely need to loop over all elements and search for the ones with the right class, because `getElementsByClass` is only supported by a few browsers.